# Identify movie about an alien disease that turns people to stone

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion

Please help me identity this movie. Here are the details I remember.

- I watched this in early 2000’s as an adolescent.
- Scene of suburban U.S. where a female alien teleports into the town via portal on the street. Humans are familiar with this alien. She apparently is sick with a disease.
- The humans follow the alien to *wherever they go - very rocky, undeveloped terrain.
- The humans somehow contract the disease, possibly by touch.
- The disease makes them turn into a strange stone, and become part of the stone landscape of the alien world.
- Their skin looks like coral reef, or maybe with holes that would bother people with trypophobia.
- The people have a good relationship with the alien suffering from the disease, so turning into stone is emotional and sad.

This may have been a twilight zone, x files, or fringe type show,  or a movie. I was quite disturbed by it as a child and now I would like to revisit those memories.

Comment: were there any notable actors in the movie that you could remember?, and was the movie big budget or had cheap cgi?

Comment: https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/A_Feasibility_Study

Comment: Not an exact match to all the details you listed, but much of it lines up with the Outer Limits (1995) episode "Feasibility Study" as noted in releseabe's comment. The only details that don't line up pertain to "female alien teleports" and "humans are familiar with this alien". In Feasibility Study, an entire suburban community is scooped up by aliens to determine whether humans would make suitable slaves, but the effort is complicated by a contagious pathogen which turns its victims into more-or-less inert mineral.

Comment: @AnthonyX i never saw 1995 version of the episode, was it similar to the one i mention above? i actually recall it from the 1960s vaguely because of how the aliens looked. not sure why it needed to be remade.

Comment: @AnthonyX - I just looked it up and you are correct! Thank you so much! I suppose my mistake was that the young lady becomes attached to the alien and the town is familiar with her. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnthonyX Please post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not an exact match to all the details you listed, but much of it lines up with the Outer Limits (1995) episode "[Feasibility Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes#ep60)" which is a re-make of the [similarly-titled episode from the "original series"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Feasibility_Study). A comment compares the plot points you listed with the original series episode. The only details that don't line up with the episode I identified pertain to "female alien teleports" and "humans are familiar with this alien".

In the 1997 version of Feasibility Study, an entire suburban community is scooped up by aliens to determine whether humans would make suitable slaves, but the effort is complicated by a contagious pathogen which turns its victims into something stone-like. A young woman (played by Laura Harris) is led through a barrier separating the Earth-like environment from what looks like a wasteland, meeting an alien. The young woman's father subsequently finds his way through the barrier also, and encounters the aliens in charge of the operation who boastfully reveal their intentions.